# HAProxy TProxy support CentOS 7

Tags: haproxy

PER: [Howto Transparent proxying and binding with HAProxy and ALOHA load-balancer](http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/09/16/howto-transparent-proxying-and-binding-with-haproxy-and-aloha-load-balancer/)

Says following kernel flags set:

- `CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY`
- `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY`

in `/boot/config-<kernel>` (3.10.299---something_x86_64) I see:

- `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY`

Build kernel following steps to add TProxy support for a post was for CentOS 6 and I'm left with the same  `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY`  flag set.

Do I have enough for transparent proxy already? Is there a difference for  `CONFIG_NETFILTER_TPROXY` kernel flag from kernel in CentOS 6 2.x vs 3.10.x that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, the kernel already includes all of the relevant TPROXY support.

Comment: however lsmod | grep -i tproxy returns nothing. So who to believe? /boot/config- file or lsmod ??

Comment: You wouldn't have a module loaded unless you tried to start using it! Have you actually attempted to set this up? It really does work.

Comment: Yes,  you were correct.  SOLVED >w/ modprobe xt_TPROXY

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is already there:

```
grep TPROX /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

it is

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=m
CONFIG_NF_TPROXY_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_TPROXY_IPV6=m
```

m means it is compiled as a kernel module

Check for the module file:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep -i tproxy
```

They are there:

```
/lib/modules/4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_tproxy_ipv4.ko.xz
/lib/modules/4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64/kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/nf_tproxy_ipv6.ko.xz
/lib/modules/4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_TPROXY.ko.xz
```

Is it already loaded ?

```
lsmod | grep tproxy
```

(no output means: not loaded)

See which ones we can load:

```
modprobe -c | grep tproxy
```

Shows:

```
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_get_sock_v4 nf_tproxy_ipv4
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_get_sock_v6 nf_tproxy_ipv6
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_handle_time_wait4 nf_tproxy_ipv4
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_handle_time_wait6 nf_tproxy_ipv6
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_laddr4 nf_tproxy_ipv4
alias symbol:nf_tproxy_laddr6 nf_tproxy_ipv6
```

Load the one(s) we want:

```
modprobe nf_tproxy_ipv6
```

Now check again to see if it is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep tprox
```

Yes this time:

```
nf_tproxy_ipv6         16384  0
```